# Problems with simple bode plots using bodeplot package

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I'm trying to plot the most simple Bode plot of the most simple lowpass filter function, given as G(s) = 1/(s+1).
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bodeplot}

\begin{document}
\BodeTF{num/{0,1},den/{1,1},d/0}{0.01}{100}
\end{document}
```

Gain plot seems ok - phase plot doesn't show expected (i. e.: NOTHING! Plus giving errors). What am I doing wrong?

=== EDIT 26-SEP-2023 ===

In Overleaf it works fine, using TexLive 2023. Just updated my MikTeX installation on my desktop PC - still no phase plot. Here's the log:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (MiKTeX 23.9.24) (format=lualatex 2023.9.26)  26 SEP 2023 07:21
 system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
Lua module: luaotfload 2023-08-31 3.26 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/lu
atex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-08-19.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/font
loader-2023-08-19.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.133
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/lu
atex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (C:/Users/PC/AppData/Lo
cal/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/bodeplot/bodeplot.sty
Package: bodeplot 

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.st
y
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks17
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/04/15 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)
\@envbody=\toks18
) (C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revisi
on.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2021/05/15 v1.18.1 Data Visualization (1.18.1)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks19
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 107.
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen140
\Gin@req@width=\dimen141
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-co
mmon.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks20
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen142
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen143
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-la
tex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.cod
e.tex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.c
ode.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.co
de.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks21
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks22

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslib
raryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks23
))
\pgf@x=\dimen144
\pgf@y=\dimen145
\pgf@xa=\dimen146
\pgf@ya=\dimen147
\pgf@xb=\dimen148
\pgf@yb=\dimen149
\pgf@xc=\dimen150
\pgf@yc=\dimen151
\pgf@xd=\dimen152
\pgf@yd=\dimen153
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count191
\c@pgf@countb=\count192
\c@pgf@countc=\count193
\c@pgf@countd=\count194
\t@pgf@toka=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks25
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks26
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count195

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-luatex.def

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-l
uatex.def
File: pgfsys-luatex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-c
ommon-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysso
ftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count196
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count197
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyspr
otocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 227.

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.c
ode.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.te
x
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.cod
e.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.c
ode.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen154
\pgfmath@count=\count198
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks27
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks28
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks29
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunction
s.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunction
s.basic.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunction
s.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunction
s.random.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunction
s.comparison.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunction
s.base.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunction
s.round.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunction
s.misc.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunction
s.integerarithmetics.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.cod
e.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.co
de.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count199
))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepo
ints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen155
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen156
\pgf@picminy=\dimen157
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen158
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen159
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen161
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen162
\pgf@xx=\dimen163
\pgf@xy=\dimen164
\pgf@yx=\dimen165
\pgf@yy=\dimen166
\pgf@zx=\dimen167
\pgf@zy=\dimen168
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepa
thconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen169
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen170
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepa
thusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen171
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen172
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoresc
opes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count266
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregr
aphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen173
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretr
ansformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen174
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen176
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequ
ick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreob
jects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepa
thprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorear
rows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen177
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoresh
ade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen178
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count267
\pgf@shadingcount=\count268
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreim
age.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreex
ternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorela
yers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretr
ansparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepa
tterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerd
f.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulesha
pes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplo
t.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-
version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen179
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen180
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-
version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.co
de.tex))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.te
x))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.cod
e.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen181
\pgffor@skip=\dimen182
\pgffor@stack=\toks30
\pgffor@toks=\toks31
))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/t
ikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrary
plothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count269
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen183
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen184
\tikz@lasty=\dimen185
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen186
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen189
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen190
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen191
\tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59
\tikz@tempbox=\box60
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count270
\tikznumberofchildren=\count271
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count272
\tikz@fig@count=\count273

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulemat
rix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count274
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count275
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count276
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count277

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/l
ibraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.t
ex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.co
de.tex
Package pgfplots info on input line 124: Initializing with LUA version Lua 5.3
\pgfplots@luabackend@table=\catcodetable14
\t@pgfplots@toka=\toks32
\t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks33
\t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks34
\pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen192
\c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count278
\c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count279

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssys
generic.code.tex))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotsli
brary.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/
pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrary
fpu.code.tex)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary utilities for your pgf version...
\t@pgf@toka=\toks35
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks36
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks37

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/
pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/luamath/pg
flibraryluamath.code.tex)
Package pgfplots info on input line 290: luamath library shipped with pgf 3.1.1
0 is up-to-date
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsut
il.code.tex
Package pgfplots info on input line 82: Found new luatex: initializing lua comm
ands instead of write18 (shell-escape)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/p
gfplotsliststructure.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/p
gfplotsliststructureext.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/p
gfplotsarray.code.tex
\c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count280
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/p
gfplotsmatrix.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplo
tstableshared.code.tex
\c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count281
\t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks38
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/p
gfplotsdeque.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbi
nary.code.tex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbi
nary.data.code.tex))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsut
il.verb.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrary
pgfplots.surfshading.code.tex
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count282

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibraryp
gfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-luatex.def)))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsco
lormap.code.tex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsco
lor.code.tex))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstacked
plots.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothan
dlers.code.tex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplo
thandler.code.tex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplo
timage.code.tex)))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scalin
g.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordpr
ocessing.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorb
ars.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.marker
s.code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.c
ode.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.
code.tex)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/l
ibraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledec
orations.code.tex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen193
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen194
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen195
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen196
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen197
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count283
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen198
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen199
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box62
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/l
ibraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decoration
s/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/l
ibraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decoration
s/pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrar
ypgfplots.contourlua.code.tex)
\pgfplots@numplots=\count284
\pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen256
\pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen257
\pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen258
\pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen259
\pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen260
\pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen261
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/l
ibraries/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrary
plotmarks.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrar
ypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex
\pgfplots@group@current@plot=\count285
\pgfplots@group@current@row=\count286
\pgfplots@group@current@column=\count287

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/l
ibraries/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
\c@gnuplot@id=\count288
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex
.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count289
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box63
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3
.

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count290
\scratchdimen=\dimen262
\scratchbox=\box64
\nofMPsegments=\count291
\nofMParguments=\count292
\everyMPshowfont=\toks39
\MPscratchCnt=\count293
\MPscratchDim=\dimen263
\MPnumerator=\count294
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count295
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks40
)
(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base
.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}).

Package pgfplots info on input line 4: Using 'lua backend=false' for axis: xmod
e=log unsupported (yet).

\openout3 = test1.gnuplot
PGFPlots: reading {test1.table}
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 4.
Package pgfplots info on input line 4: Using 'lua backend=false' for axis: xmod
e=log unsupported (yet).

\openout3 = test2.gnuplot
PGFPlots: reading {test2.table}

Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been
 filtered away) on input line 4.

 [warning /pgfplots/warning/plot without coordinates]

Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). R
eplacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 4.

 [warning /pgfplots/warning/empty range cleared axis]
[1

{C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 23799 strings out of 477259
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 413 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 5 attribute_list, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:2500,3:1759,4:46,5:23,6:2,7:1074,8:5,9:308,11:2
 44440 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 26 fonts using 1477063 bytes
 114i,9n,111p,743b,2215s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<//?/c:/users/pc/appdata/local/programs/miktex/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman1
0-regular.otf><//?/c:/users/pc/appdata/local/programs/miktex/fonts/opentype/publ
ic/lm/lmroman8-regular.otf><C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi6.pfb><C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb><C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb><C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX
```

Comment: I ran your code on Overleaf, and the output shows fine, with a reasonable looking phase plot. You said "plus giving errors": what exactly are the errors shown?

Comment: Sorry ... Overleaf doesn't work either, giving error "LaTeX Error: File `bodeplot.sty' not found."

Comment: TexLive / Lualatex gives "Package PGF Plots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away) on input line 4" and "You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 4."

Comment: Overleaf does work for me. I tried both TeXLive 2022/2023 with both pdflatex and lualatex. Are you using Overleaf with a really old TeXLive (before bodeplot.sty was added to CTAN?) //  Is your TeXLive installation up to date? Try pasting the log (at least the part with the package versions).

Comment: This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (MiKTeX 23.1) (format=lualatex 2023.2.22)  26 SEP 2023 06:58
 system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-10-03 3.23 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.

Comment: Sorry ... seems that I am not allowed to edit my post

Comment: I'll flag a moderator to reach out. All users should be allowed to edit their own questions.

Comment: @StringChecker, Sometimes it helps to delete all files besides your .tex file and to compile again.

Comment: @StringChecker: At the bottom of your post (and above the comments) you should see a list of "buttons": Share, Edit, Follow, Close. Click on Edit to updated your post if needed.

Comment: Thanks so far for replies. @MS-SPO: That didn't help. In fact, I did complete reinstall of TexLive 2023 on my desktop and notebook PC, same problem. In Overleaf with TexLive 2023, it works fine. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Found it:
Not a TeX/LaTeX problem.

I had gnuplot 5.2 installed ... after updating to recent 5.4 version, everything is fine.